# Adding elements to a field widget in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

What I need to accomplish is adding a link to a node to field widgets (the node contains the formatted instructions to properly compile the field).

So far I've been able to add the node reference field in the field config form, using Third Party Settings:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'field_config_edit_form' && $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->get('entity_type') == 'myentity') {

    $field = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    $help_page_id = $field->getThirdPartySetting('mymodule', 'help_page_id');

    $form['help_page_id'] = array(
      '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
      '#title' => t('Help page'),
      '#target_type' => 'node',
      '#selection_handler' => 'default',
      '#selection_settings' => array(
        'target_bundles' => array('help_page'),
      ),
      '#default_value' => $help_page_id ? Node::load($help_page_id) : NULL,
      '#weight' => 100,
    );

    $form['#entity_builders'][] = 'mymodule_form_field_config_edit_form_builder';
  }
}
```

Now I'm having troubles retrieving this information when showing the form, and altering the field widget in order to display the link.
Using hook_field_widget_form_alter, I cannot get the custom configuration value from the arguments I have:

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {

}
```

I guess I have to load the field configuration entity, but I don't know how.

Comment: I guess it will be easier to find your problem seeing your code. From what you say, it's hard to know the issue, may be a problem in your code or a caching issue.

Comment: I edited the original message with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it, but something like this should work:

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  // Add a suffix to widget form elements for all fields of type entity_reference.
  $field_definition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();
  if ($field_definition->getType() == 'entity_reference') {
    // TODO: Render the node link to $link
    $element['#suffix'] = $link;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've edited the code in order the check if the third party setting is set, but your hint was correct. The context in which to look for is $context['items']->getFieldDefinition(). Thanks!